# how to share the variable in chains of function calls python

Tags: python

I have a fast API server in python. There are multiple layers for an API like one file call the function of other package and so on.

I generate request id for every request, at the top layer, now i want to share this id with evert chains of functions without passing it to the function.

In the NodeJs there is a [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/continuation-local-storage) for the same, but how can i do the same in the python?

Comment: what do you do with request id in each function call? is it just used for logging purposes or as part of theinput ?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle for the time being logging purpose

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround which I used in a similar scenario.
Create a python file, say sess.py, in which you can have a variable request_id defined as below.

```
request_id=""
```

Now, you can import sess.py as below in any file in you application.

```
import sess
sess.request_id=1
```

And use this anywhere in your application.